# How to get the job id whenever scheduler is running

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I am scheduling one activity in spring boot and using TaskScheduler for that.

```
taskScheduler.schedule(Runnable task, new PeriodicTrigger(duration));
```

The above code I’m calling via restendpoint. Whenever I’m calling the restendpoint with new value the Runnabletask is getting changed and the scheduler is executing with the new value.

I want the scheduler value to be same if I’ve scheduled it first time with some value and the next scheduled activity should run with the value which I passed during that time and so on.

Todo so I am planning to Persist the data somewhere with pk as jobid and whenever scheduler is running before execution get the jobid and fetch the data associated with the jobid and then perform the action

Comment: What do you mean exactly with scheduler value? The name of the thread? The duration?

Comment: I am passing some value to the runnabletask.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem but let me try to guess. If you reuse the same instance of runnable task for successive calls then there will be only one value and it will be updated. Maybe you should create a new instance every time? But be aware of memory usage. If you call 100k times - you will get 100k objects.